# Is if/else/if possible in list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'd like to know if it is possible to use a list comprehension with `if`/ `else` that need not result in a list of the same length as the length of the list being processed? (ie. without the final `else`)

```
>>> L = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> [v * 10 if v < 3 else v * 2 if v > 3 else v for v in L] #if/else/if/else
[0, 10, 20, 3, 8, 10, 12]
```

works fine. But suppose I want to omit the 3, to get:

```
[0, 10, 20, 8, 10, 12]  # No number 3
```

I would have thought this would work:

```
>>> [v * 10 if v < 3 else v * 2 if v > 3 for v in L] #if/else/if
```

But it is a syntax error..

So I thought 'maybe' this would work:

```
>>> [v * 10 if v < 3 else v * 2 if v > 3 else pass for v in L] #if/else/if/else pass
```

But it doesn't..

This is a curiosity question, I realise this is not neccessarily the most readable/appropriate approach to the above processing.

Am I missing something? Can it be done?
(I'm on python 2.6.5)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, that's possible:

```
[foo for foo in bar if foo.something]
```

Or in your case:

```
[v * 10 if v < 3 else v * 2 for v in L if v != 3]
```

I's also mentioned in [the docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: Not everything has to be a list comp!

Comment: It can help to imagine it as a normal list comprehension `[expr_of_x for x in iterable if expr_of_x]`, but where `(a if b else c)` is the expression. You can even keep the parentheses to make the list comprehension more obvious to readers.

Answer (score 4):

Put the filtering condition after the loop:

```
 [v * 10 if v < 3 else v * 2 for v in L if v != 3]
```

returns

```
[0, 10, 20, 8, 10, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    A=[[x*2, x*10][x <3] for x in L if x!=3]
```

Comment: Can you explain *why* this solves the question? This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its **length** and **content**. See [answer].

Answer (score -2):

Whats wrong with doing

```
out = []
for v in L:
    if v < 3:
        out.append(v * 10)
    elif v > 3:
        out.append(v * 2)
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my fairly clear question about list comprehensions!

Comment: Not everything has to be a list comprehension